# How To Assign Same IDs to Aliases/partial identicals Strings in the same Column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

In short, I need a script or a formula able to scan the range `D2:D21` / `D2:D` for strings "partial" matches and output corresponding IDS to Basic Strings Cells and their partial match cells in `E2:E21` / `E2:E` .

I have this minimal testing example:

[image: IDs]

[Assign Same IDs to Aliases/partial identicals Strings](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LaIGBWdhofUYb8_HzWREC6NKkPxjXhIQxXYcm6Don24/edit?usp=sharing)

| ORDERED DATA | IDS |  | WORKING DATASET | EXPECTED RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BYTE | id_0 |  | U SHORT (VAR 1) | id_3 |
| S BYTE | id_1 |  | S BYTE (VAR2) | id_1 |
| SHORT | id_2 |  | BYTE (VAR2) | id_0 |
| U SHORT | id_3 |  | BYTE | id_0 |
| INT | id_4 |  | INT | id_4 |
| BYTE (VAR 1) |  |  | S BYTE | id_1 |
| S BYTE (VAR 1) |  |  | INT (VAR 1) | id_4 |
| SHORT (VAR 1) |  |  | S BYTE (VAR 1) | id_1 |
| U SHORT (VAR 1) |  |  | U SHORT (VAR2) | id_3 |
| INT (VAR 1) |  |  | SHORT (VAR2) | id_2 |
| BYTE (VAR2) |  |  | S BYTE (VAR'3) | id_1 |
| S BYTE (VAR2) |  |  | SHORT | id_2 |
| SHORT (VAR2) |  |  | U SHORT | id_3 |
| U SHORT (VAR2) |  |  | BYTE (VAR 1) | id_0 |
| INT (VAR2) |  |  | U SHORT (VAR'3) | id_3 |
| BYTE (VAR'3) |  |  | SHORT (VAR'3) | id_2 |
| S BYTE (VAR'3) |  |  | INT (VAR2) | id_4 |
| SHORT (VAR'3) |  |  | BYTE (VAR'3) | id_0 |
| U SHORT (VAR'3) |  |  | INT (VAR'3) | id_4 |
| INT (VAR'3) |  |  | SHORT (VAR 1) | id_2 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| BASIC STRINGS | IDS |  |  |  |
| BYTE | id_0 |  |  |  |
| S BYTE | id_1 |  |  |  |
| SHORT | id_2 |  |  |  |
| U SHORT | id_3 |  |  |  |
| INT | id_4 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| BASIC STRINGS VARIANTS 1 | IDS | BASIC STRINGS VARIANTS 2 | IDS | BASIC STRINGS VARIANTS 3 |
| BYTE (VAR 1) | id_0 | BYTE (VAR2) | id_0 | BYTE (VAR'3) |
| S BYTE (VAR 1) | id_1 | S BYTE (VAR2) | id_1 | S BYTE (VAR'3) |
| SHORT (VAR 1) | id_2 | SHORT (VAR2) | id_2 | SHORT (VAR'3) |
| U SHORT (VAR 1) | id_3 | U SHORT (VAR2) | id_3 | U SHORT (VAR'3) |
| INT (VAR 1) | id_4 | INT (VAR2) | id_4 | INT (VAR'3) |

Basically, I need the same IDS from `B2:B6` to be assigned to all aliases of `A2:A6` source data strings, as in `E2:E21`.

Aliases are all cells having identical matches but ending with extra "attributes" in parentheses.

For example `BYTE (VAR 1)` or `BYTE (VAR2)` or `BYTE (VAR'3)` are all aliases of `BYTE`.

Or, `S BYTE (VAR 1)` or `S BYTE (VAR2)` or `S BYTE (VAR'3)` are all aliases of `S BYTE`.

The WORKING DATASET in `D2:D21` is not ordered, and not even (there are instances of `A2:A6` source data strings with 0, 1 or 2, or 3 (or ideally n) number of aliases.

The expected result in `E2:E21` shows the same IDS being assigned to the source data cells and its aliases cells.

I've looked at `VLOOKUP` and `SCAN` functions but it seems those can only work with full matches or parital matches on numerical approaching matches but not with substrings partial matches. Or if they are, I'm not sure how to make it work.

I also considered manually removing the aliases attributes substrings, then using Vlookup, then adding back the attributes manually. Which is error prone and lenghty process. And doesn't work past the basic strings range (`F2:L21` in below screenshots).

[image: 0]

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Any idea on a better approach is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=index(vlookup(regexreplace(D2:D21,"( \(.*\))",""),A2:B6,2,))
```

[image]

Comment: Works great on the example thanks a lot! I'll do testing on large dataset and be back asa.